# How to split an OpenCL task into smaller chunks?

Tags: opencl, gpgpu

I am working on multiplying a long vector by another vector using OpenCL.
In particular, the second vector is in fact a cosine function where the input argument is the global_id.

As my GPU has limited RAM size (3 GB), to perform the above task for a vector larger than that, I need to chop the long vector into shorter ones, and perform that one by one.

Initially I did it by introducing offset in the clEnqueueMapBuffer function and loop over it:

```
void* p_map_inV = clEnqueueMapBuffer(queue, d_inV, CL_TRUE, CL_MAP_READ, m*mem_size_chunk, mem_size_chunk, 0, NULL, NULL, &error);
```

where m is a looping variable. This seems to work, but I realized the time it takes with increasing vector length is more than linear. That led me to think there was some overhead and maybe I used a wrong method.

Do you think I can somehow do this by executing the kernel separately instead? For example, adding an offset to the global_id?

Appreciated if you can let me know the typical way this is done, as I kind of guess this is common.

Comment: Can you describe how do you loop across the different chunks? We need more information to be able to help

Comment: HI Ruyk, Thanks for the comment, I think it has been solved and the performance might be caused by something else. In any case, the code is now working like:Create buffer of a safe size for the GPU-->for loop start-->transfer data from host to device by using pointer to note the starting position-->compute-->write from device to host-->repeat-->for loop ends